# Plugin Image Doesn't Display

Tags: plugins, icons

I've created a plugin in Banno People, Settings, External Applications.  On the Dashboard configuration Plugin Option page, we can choose the icon that will appear.  I enabled the Plugin just for my username - when I access Banno Desktop its there, but shows an error icon and a "refused to connect" message.  I opened a JHA case and they directed me to this site.  Any ideas?

Plugin should appear with the icon I selected.  The plugin link to the third party site is working.